# transposing rows and columns in multiple data frames in list

Tags: r, lapply

I have a multiple data frames in a list.I want to apply this function to each dataframe.

```
    df = data.frame(x = c("P1","P2","P3","P4","P5"),
                y = c("DC","DC","DC","DC","DC"),
                f_1 = c("NA","1","NA","NA","NA"), 
                f_2= c("NA","1","NA","NA","NA"),
                f_3= c("1","7","NA","NA","NA"),
                f_4= c("NA","NA","5","NA","NA"),
                f_5= c("NA","NA","2","NA","NA"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1 = data.frame(x = c("P1","P8","P10","P4","P11"),
                 y = c("RC","RC","RC","RC","RC"),
                f_1 = c("5","1","NA","NA","NA"), 
                f_2= c("NA","1","7","NA","NA"),
                f_3= c("1","7","NA","9","NA"),
                f_4= c("NA","NA","5","NA","NA"),
                f_5= c("NA","NA","2","NA","10"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 = data.frame(x = c("P11","P22","P23","P44","P25"),
                 y = c("PC","PC","PC","PC","PC"),
                f_1 = c("NA","1","2","NA","6"), 
                f_2= c("NA","1","NA","NA","NA"),
                f_3= c("1","7","NA","NA","NA"),
                f_4= c("NA","3","5","NA","NA"),
                f_5= c("5","NA","2","NA","NA"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DF<-list(df,df1,df2)
```

I am trying to gather every rows of data frame into column against each first column value.I want to do this in lapply method but not know the correct syntax.

i have tried but not getting the correct output.I have also tried gather function but not succeed.

```
lapply(DF,function(x){
  t(x)[,c(2:6)]})

Desire output:  



 DF[[1]]

    x   y    F
    P1  DC   NA 
    P2  DC   1 
    P3  DC   NA
    P4  DC   10
    P5  DC   NA
    P1  DC   NA
    P2..DC   1
```

Does anyone know ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `pivot_longer` after looping over the `list` with `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
map(DF, ~ .x %>%
             pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('f'), values_to = "F") %>% 
            select(-name))
#[[1]]
# A tibble: 25 x 3
#   x     y     F    
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 P1    DC    NA   
# 2 P1    DC    NA   
# 3 P1    DC    1    
# 4 P1    DC    NA   
# 5 P1    DC    NA   
# 6 P2    DC    1    
# 7 P2    DC    1    
# 8 P2    DC    7    
# 9 P2    DC    NA   
#10 P2    DC    NA   
# … with 15 more rows

#[[2]]
# A tibble: 25 x 3
#   x     y     F    
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 P1    RC    5    
# 2 P1    RC    NA   
# 3 P1    RC    1    
# 4 P1    RC    NA   
# 5 P1    RC    NA   
# 6 P8    RC    1    
# 7 P8    RC    1    
# 8 P8    RC    7    
# 9 P8    RC    NA   
#10 P8    RC    NA   
# … with 15 more rows

#[[3]]
# A tibble: 25 x 3
#   x     y     F    
#   <chr> <chr> <chr>
# 1 P11   PC    NA   
# 2 P11   PC    NA   
# 3 P11   PC    1    
# 4 P11   PC    NA   
# 5 P11   PC    5    
# 6 P22   PC    1    
# 7 P22   PC    1    
# 8 P22   PC    7    
# 9 P22   PC    3    
#10 P22   PC    NA   
# … with 15 more rows
```

---

If we don't have column names same across `list`, then we can use index

```
map(DF, ~ .x %>%
         pivot_longer(cols = 3:ncol(.), values_to = "F") %>% 
        select(-name))
```

Comment: its seems good but every column is not starting with letter 'f'.